# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on Arch (postgresql)

Tags: arch-linux, libraries, postgresql

I can't install `gem pg` on Arch due to the error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... no
No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... no
Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/ruby
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/pg-0.17.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0/pg-0.17.1/gem_make.out
```

even so I've installed `sudo pacman -S libmariadbclient`. I've had this error on Ubuntu, but there I was able to solve it by install pgdev (I don't remember exactly) library. The fact is, this library doesn't exist for arch in its repository or it's called differently.

Comment: You need to find out what Arch package contains `libpq-fe.h` and `pg_config`.

Comment: @CraigRinger, how?

Comment: If I knew that it'd be an answer not a comment ;-) . I don't use Arch. I'd start with a Google search like "arch package containing libpq-fe.h" though, or "arch package containing file"

Comment: @CraigRinger, there must be an easier way I figure.

Comment: Well, on Fedora/Ubuntu/CentOS/RHEL/Debian there is, but Arch is a bit ... odd ... and I'm not really familiar with it. So no idea.

Comment: @CraigRinger, you were awfully right!

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo pacman -S postgresql-libs
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [@Craig Ringer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143897/error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension-on-arch-postgresql/264729#comment231789_143897), search for the package that contains "libpq-fe.h". I use pkgfile for that:

```
pacman -S pkgfile
pkgfile --update
pkgfile --search libpq-fe.h
```

Which returns "postgresql-libs". Install that package, as mentioned by @inn0kenty.

I just had the same problem and I solved it using those steps.

Comment: Your answer would be much better if it was complete and concise. You can reference other's posts, but don't force everyone to search for them to find out what you had in mind.